# How can I load css files in webview in Electron?

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I'm injecting javascript (preloading javascript file) into webview in Electron app to modify some CSS of the content in the webview, but there seems not to be a way to load CSS files in webview.

Does anyone knows how to load CSS files into webview in Electron? So I can use preloaded javascript to modify the DOM elements in the webview.

Attempt 1:
I tried to load a CSS file (Injecting the CSS file) from the preloaded script like this, but `remote.getGlobal('dirPath')}` part will be appended to the `src` url of the current webview, so (i.e. `https://stackoverflow.com/User/path/to/my/app/directory/public/css/inject.cs`)

My current solution:
But I found a way to inject css via javascript file that is preloaded.

```
if (!document.getElementById(cssId)) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var sty = document.createElement('style');
  sty.type = 'text/css';
  var css = '.your_css_class { background: red }'; // You can compress all css files you need and put here
  if (sty.styleSheet){
    sty.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    sty.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  head.appendChild(sty);
}
```

References:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/

And `preload` does not allow to load multiple files (I'm already using it to load a javascript file):
[How to preload multiple js in electron webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626780/how-to-preload-multiple-js-in-electron-webview)

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5325