# Is there a way by which I can have separate preload.js files for my html

Tags: html, node.js, electron

So I was wondering if there's any possible way of having separate files for my html files
I couldn't find anything helpful on YouTube or github

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41627271/2550156 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/68236882/2550156 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @pergy doesnt work for me it still says "require is not defined"